# Safe Arabic Web Fonts that can be used in ASP.net based website and how can we use custom font in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webfonts

I have been working on a multilingual website which has been developed in ASP.net 4.0 (C#). I am using Tahoma for the English version and i am not sure which font i should use for Arabic version. I have used Arabic Transparent which come up nice and to my surprise i cant find this font installed on my system. Another part of question is how can i used custom font in ASP.Net website. I would appreciate any help in this regards.

I have Google but could not find example on how to choose orf which are the safe Arabic fonts which will work across all major browsers.

I have few option for Arabic Simplified Arabic, Arial, Times New Roman, Transparent Arabic and i cant find much material if any of these fonts are supported by all major browsers or Operation system.

Any one with Experience in Arabic development may come handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find good examples of arabic fonts which you can use in your web projects. http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/Project/ChooseFonts?fontQuery=arabic#languages%3DW20%26page%3D1

Comment: Are these safe fonts and supported across all major browsers

Comment: yes web fonts created and tested on almost all major browers. you can test fonts directly on all browsers.

Comment: @Irfan, Appreciate your answer they come up nicely in all browser for some reason i am hesitant to use as i cant find any of these fonts installed on my system and still they come up right... I am sure you must have experience of working with Arabic design and know more about it.

Comment: There is no need of installation on computer, all you need to download fonts, store font files on your server where your website hosted, and use these fonts. when any user try to access your websites, automatically these fonts will be downloaded along with website and loaded.